# How to get different colors in different terminals like BlackArch Linux

Tags: command-line

BlackArch Linux has 4 different color terminals (terminal green, terminal red, terminal yellow and  terminal white). Is there any way for me to set up something similar in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `terminator` terminal emulator(install via `sudo apt-get install terminator`). The default `gnome-terminal` does not have this capability.

With `terminator` you can have 4 different profiles, which you can apply to each "window" and then go to Right Click -> Preference -> Layouts , and add new layout.

[image]

Now, one can launch terminator with `terminator --layout CUSTOM` command

Comment: Thanks. That's it what I am looking for. It working fine. Thanks a lot.